# I do not know how to optimize

Tags: php

I do not know how to optimize the generation of:

```
$choices = Array
(
    ["00"] => "00"
    ["01"] => "01"
    ["02"] => "02"
    ["03"] => "03"
    ["04"] => "04"
    ["05"] => "05'
    ["06"] => "06"
    ["07"] => "07"
    ["08"] => "08"
    ["09"] => "09"
    ["10"] => "10"
    ["11"] => "11"
    ["12"] => "12"
    ["13"] => "13"
    ["14"] => "14"
    ["15"] => "15"
    ["16"] => "16"
    ["17"] => "17"
    ["18"] => "18"
    ["19"] => "19"
    ["20"] => "20"
    ["21"] => "21"
    ["22"] => "22"
    ["23"] => "23"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`range`](http://php.net/range) function:

```
$choices = range(0, 22);
```

You can do a `foreach` and a `strval`, if you absolutely need a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, unless you're getting the maximum value from an external process, you shouldn't try to optimize it. Explicitly specifying each key and value in this manner is faster than calculating them on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

The "range" function won't render the same array
use instead:

```
$choices = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 23; $i++) {
    $choices[str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)] = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For string you can do it like this

```
$choices = range(0, 22);

function makestring($value){
    return (string)$value;
}


$result = array_map('makestring',$choices,array_keys($choices));
```